# LISP FUNCTION - Return the count of numbers of the list that are bigger of the first element

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to solve a lisp function that returns a NUMBER(count) of numbers which are greater than the first number in the list.The list is a linear list of numbers.

```
(defun foo (lst) 
  (cond ((null lst) 0)
        (car = k)
        ((> (car lst) k) 
        (1+ (foo (cdr lst))))
  (T (foo (cdr lst)))))
```

My problem is that I cannot keep the first element and compare it with the others.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_countc.htm

Comment: (defun foo (lst) 
  (cond
    ((null lst) 0)
    (car = k)
    ((> (car lst) k) 
      (1+ (foo (cdr lst))))
    (T
      (foo (cdr lst)))))

Comment: im not so familiar with lisp because im newbie..i think that im close , but my problem is that i cannot keep the first element and compare it with the others

Comment: @TasosCe: what does it mean you cannot 'keep the first element'? Do you know what a variable is?

Comment: that means that i know how to read the list, element by element ,but i dont know how to compare every element with the first one of the list.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Can you help me with that if it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function indented correctly looks like this:

```lisp
(defun foo (lst) 
  (cond ((null lst) 0) 
        (car = k)              ; strange cond term         
        ((> (car lst) k)        
         (1+ (foo (cdr lst))))
        (T (foo (cdr lst)))))
```

I have commented the second term in your cond. It is quite strange. It first evaluates the *variable* `car` (not the function `#'car`). If `car` is not `nil` it first evaluates the variable `=` (not the function `#'=`) and since it is not the last consequent expression in the `cond` term it throws that away and returns the last which is `k`.

Secondly you write that you say you use the first element as comparison, however you call it `k` in your function but it is not defined anywhere. You need to do something before you do the recursion and thus you cannot let the actual function do the recursion since it will take the first element each time. Here is where `labels` can be used:

```lisp
;; didn't call it foo since it's not very descriptive
(defun count-larger-than-first (list)
  (let ((first (car list)))
    (labels ((helper (list)
               (cond ((null list) 0)
                     ((> (car list) first) 
                      (1+ (helper (cdr list))))
                     (t (helper (cdr list))))))
      (helper (cdr list)))))
```

Of course. Since you now have  the possibility to add more arguments I would have added an accumulator:

```lisp
(defun count-larger-than-first (list)
  (let ((first (car list)))
    (labels ((helper (list acc)
               (cond ((null list) acc)
                     ((> (car list) first) 
                      (helper (cdr list) (1+ acc)))
                     (t (helper (cdr list) acc)))))
      (helper (cdr list) 0))))
```

And of course recursion might blow the stack so you should really write it without in Common Lisp:

```lisp
(defun count-larger-than-first (list)
  (let ((first (car list)))
    (loop :for element :in (cdr list)
          :counting (> element first))))
```

There are higher order functions that count too which might be more suitable:

```lisp
(defun count-larger-than-first (list)
  (let ((first (car list)))
    (count-if (lambda (element) (> element first))
              (cdr list))))
```

Comment: Really thank you about your help.I tested it and it works perfect! Also , thank you for your helpful advice at the start, i understood everything about my mistake with the k and the use of the labels :) !!

Answer (score 5):

Let's take apart your problem:

You have a set of numbers. Really, you have a “special” first number, and then the rest of them. Specifically, you probably want only real numbers, because “less than” does not make sense in terms of complex (imaginary) numbers.

You can use `first` to get the first number from the list, and `rest` for the others.

Of these, you want to count any that are not greater than the first.

So let's start with sort of pseudocode

```
(defun count-numbers-greater-than-first (list)
  ;; split out first and rest
  ;; call the real count function
  )
```

Well, we know now that we can use `first` and `rest` (also, as you used, historically `car` and `cdr`), so:

```
(defun count-numbers-greater-than-first (list)
   (count-numbers-greater-than (first list) (rest list))
```

You already probably know that `>` is used to test whether real numbers are greater than one another.

A quick look at the CLHS reveals a nice function called `count-if`

```
(defun count-numbers-not-greater-than (reference other-numbers)
    (count-if ??? other-numbers))
```

The `???` needs to be an object of `function` type, or the name of a function. We need to “curry” the `reference` (first number) into that function. This means we want to create a new function, that is only used for one run through the `count-if`, that already has “closed over” the value of `reference`.

If we knew that `number` would always be, say, `100`, that function would look like this:

```
(defun greater-than-100 (number)
    (> number 100))
```

That function could then get used in the `count-if`:

```
(defun count-numbers-greater-than (reference other-numbers)
    (count-if (function greater-than-100)
              other-numbers))

(defun count-numbers-greater-than (reference other-numbers)
    (count-if #'greater-than-100 other-numbers))
```

But that doesn't solve the problem of getting the `reference` number “curried” into the function.

Without reaching for Alexandria (I'll explain in a moment), you can use a `lambda` form to create a new, anonymous function right here. Since `reference` is available within `count-numbers-not-greater-than`, you can use its value within that `lambda`. Let's convert for 100 first:

```
(defun count-numbers-greater-than (reference other-numbers)
    (count-if (lambda (number) (> number 100))
              other-numbers))
```

Now we can use `reference`:

```
(defun count-numbers-greater-than (reference other-numbers)
    (count-if (lambda (number) (> number reference))
              other-numbers))
```

And, in fact, you could even merge this back into the other function, if you wanted:

```
(defun count-numbers-greater-than-first (list)
    (count-if (lambda (number) (> number (first list)))
              (rest list)))
```

## That Alexandria thing

But, what about Alexandria? Alexandria is a collection of super-useful utility functions that's available in Quicklisp or elsewhere.

```
 (ql:quickload "alexandria")

 (use-package #:alexandria)
```

Of course, you'd normally `use` it in your own `defpackage`

```
 (defpackage my-cool-program
   (:use :common-lisp :alexandria))
```

Two of the things it provides are `curry` and `rcurry` functions. It turns out, that `lambda` function in there is a really common case. You have an existing function — here, `>` — that you want to call with the same value over and over, and also some unknown value that you want to pass in each time.

These end up looking a lot like this:

```
 (lambda (x) (foo known x))
```

You can use `curry` to write the same thing more concisely:

```
 (curry #'foo known)
```

It also work with any number of arguments. `RCurry` does the same, but it puts the unknown values “x” at the left, and your known values at the right.

```
 (lambda (x) (foo x known)) = (rcurry #'foo known)
```

So another way to write the `count-if` is:

```
(defun count-numbers-greater-than-first (list)
    (count-if (rcurry #'> (first list))
              (rest list)))

 * (count-numbers-greater-than-first '(10 9 8 7 11 12))

 2
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much about the good explanation , every solution works perfect and it was fully understandable!